# AngularJS directive with transclude from a promise ($resource)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, promise

I am completely new to Angular and have been attempting to make a simple blog to get to know some of the features.

The design I have is a JSON API for posts, which include a post title, created and updated dates and a post body, which is formatted as markdown.

A post is rendered with a directive `singlePost` (and there is another directive for a list of posts for the home page). `singlePost` doesn't do anything interesting or special, it simply includes a template that also has a call to another directive, `markdown`.

Posts are acquired by the following service:

```
.factory('PostService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/posts/:id', {
        id: '@id'
    });
}])
```

The controller that uses it looks like this:

```
.controller('PostController', function($scope, $routeParams, PostService) {
    $scope.post = PostService.get({id: $routeParams.id});
})
```

And `markdown` currently looks like this:

```
.directive('markdown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('content', function(value) {
                var showdown = new Showdown.converter();
                element.removeAttr('content');
                element.html(showdown.makeHtml(value));
            });
        }
    }
})
```

This works fine. The markdown is placed in the attribute `content` and then is seen by `$observe` when the promise resolves from the service. The library Showdown is then used to convert this into HTML and then that is placed onto the page. To remove the issue of having an attribute with an entire post in it, I am simply removing the attribute.

Despite this working, it seems strange to do it this way. Having an attribute left over with a bunch of content in it is clearly not right. However, I couldn't get transclusion to work in this scenario because `post.body` doesn't exist until the service promise is resolved.

How would I go about implementing this so I could write `<markdown>{{post.body}}</markdown>`?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried with the transclution?